# Downloading from S3 using a direct request in Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, urllib

with given

```
bucket = 'mybucket'
aws_id = '.....'
aws_secret_key = '........'

file_key = '/some/file/key'
range = '40-2000'
```

I would like to send a request via Python, to get the respective part of the file.

I adapted the EC2 (first) example from [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html) -

```
import sys, os, base64, datetime, hashlib, hmac 
import requests # I would prefer urllib or anything that comes with Python

host = 's3.amazonaws.com'
region = 'us-east-1'
endpoint = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com'

# Amazon's key signing logic
def sign(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()

def getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName):
    kDate = sign(('AWS4' + key).encode('utf-8'), dateStamp)
    kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
    kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
    return kSigning

# Create a date for headers and the credential string
t = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
amzdate = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
datestamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d') # Date w/o time, used in credential scope

# Create a signing key from the aws_secret_key
signing_key = getSignatureKey(aws_secret_key, datestamp, region, 's3')

# Generate request parts -  What canonical_querystring is required for downloading (part of) a file?
canonical_querystring = '???'  # This string is appended to the endpoint url when the request is sent
canonical_headers = 'host:' + host + '\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + amzdate + '\n'
signed_headers = 'host;x-amz-date'
payload_hash = hashlib.sha256(('').encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

# Combine elements to create canonical request, that will be used to create an authorization header
canonical_request = 'GET' + '\n' + '/' + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash

# Create hashed version of the canonical request with yet more prefixes
algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
credential_scope = datestamp + '/' + region + '/' + 's3' + '/' + 'aws4_request'
string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' +  amzdate + '\n' +  credential_scope + '\n' +  hashlib.sha256(canonical_request.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

# Sign the semi-hashed string from above using the signing key (the one we generated with our secret key)
signature = hmac.new(signing_key, (string_to_sign).encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

# Generate authorization header from the signature, access key and yet more prefixes
authorization_header = algorithm + ' ' + 'Credential=' + aws_access_key + '/' + credential_scope + ', ' +  'SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers + ', ' + 'Signature=' + signature

# Generate headers dictionary. Do I need more/other headers here for downloading a file?
headers = {'x-amz-date':amzdate, 'Authorization':authorization_header}

# The gods are shining upon us 
r = requests.get(endpoint + '?' + canonical_querystring, headers=headers)

print('Response code: %d\n' % r.status_code)

# Wish to get my bytestring here
```

I waded through boto3's source code to try to understand the mechanics of such a direct request, but couldn't converge on what needs to be done to make the snippet functional using requests / urllib.

Can anyone perhaps point out what is missing to complete the adaptation?

Comment: Are you just trying to get the contents of a file stored within S3?

Comment: yes, a specific part every time

Comment: You're doing this the incredibly difficult way.  You tagged your post with `boto3`, but aren't using it.  That's exactly what you should be looking towards.  See my answer below.

Comment: I know, but I have restricions and reason not to use boto here

Comment: So you tagged it with `boto3`, told us you already tried `boto3` and couldn't get it to work, but now you are saying that you have other reasons not to use it?  Sorry, bud.  You're on your own trying to piece it together manually.

Comment: I said I went through boto's code, not used it. Perhaps I was unclear

Comment: Why are you avoiding boto3?  There may be a solution to that answer to let you do this the easy way.

Comment: Unusual and obscure requirements is something that you definitely have to explain early in the question text. boto3 is the obvious library to use here. And if it's a requirement not to use boto3, then the question should not be tagged with the `boto3` tag.

Comment: Fair enough, I removed the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request is an http `GET`. I used [requests-toolbelt dump tool](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dumputils.html) to see how it looked like, and this is what's required:

```
s3_message_parts = ['GET {} HTTP/1.1',
                        'Host: {}',
                        'Connection: keep-alive',
                        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
                        'Accept: */*',
                        'User-Agent: ssup',
                        'X-Amz-Content-Sha256: UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD',
                        'Range: bytes={}-{}',
                        'X-Amz-Date: {}',
                        'Authorization: {}',
                        '\r\n']
```

2 tricky parts:

1. Given a bucket and a key, find out the host / endpoint with which to interact.
2. Fill up the `Authorization` header correctly.

I didn't solve 1, just supplied the endpoint that I found in advance for my bucket.

As far as 2, I managed to figure out the signing process by looking at the excellent [minio-py](https://github.com/minio/minio-py) library.

The entire manouver looks like this ([most recent version](https://gist.github.com/h5rdly/30e3dbb28f46ca5fdc404155438017c9)) :

```
import hashlib, hmac, socket, ssl
from datetime import datetime

try:
    from urlparse import urlsplit
except:
    from urllib.parse import urlsplit


ALGORTHM = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
sign = lambda key, msg: hmac.new(key, msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()


def sign_headers(headers, url, access_key, secret_key, region = 'us-east-1'):

    method = 'GET'

    # Get host and parsed datetime and date used by AWS
    parsed_url = urlsplit(url)
    host = parsed_url.netloc
    date = datetime.utcnow()
    aws_datetime = date.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")
    aws_date = date.strftime("%Y%m%d")

    # Generate scope and scoped credential strings, and the signing key
    scope = '/'.join([aws_date, region, 's3', 'aws4_request'])
    credential = '/'.join([access_key, scope])
    signing_key = sign(sign(sign(sign(('AWS4' + secret_key).encode('utf-8'), aws_date), region), 's3'), 'aws4_request') 

    # Fill up all headers except 'Authorization'
    headers['Host'] = host
    headers['X-Amz-Date'] = aws_datetime
    headers['X-Amz-Content-Sha256'] = u'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD'

    # Format header keys and data for the upcoming AWS atrings
    sorted_headers_string = ';'.join([header.lower().strip() for header in sorted(headers)])
    canonical_header_list = [header.lower().strip() + ':' + str(headers[header]).strip() for header in sorted(headers)]

    # Geenerate canonical request and string to be signed
    prefix = [method, parsed_url.path, parsed_url.query]
    suffix =  ['', sorted_headers_string, u'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD']  # '' to alow 2 '\n'    
    canonical_req = '\n'.join(prefix + canonical_header_list + suffix)
    string_to_sign = '\n'.join([ALGORTHM, aws_datetime, scope, hashlib.sha256(canonical_req.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()])
    signature = hmac.new(signing_key, string_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

    # Finally generate the Authoization header with signing string_to_sign
    headers['Authorization'] = ALGORTHM + ' Credential=' + credential + ', ' + 'SignedHeaders=' + sorted_headers_string + ', ' + 'Signature=' + signature

    return headers


def download_s3_chunk(bucket, key, start, end, access_key, secret_key, endpoint = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com', region = 'us-east-1'):
    ''' Download part of an S3 stored file using vanilla Python '''

    headers = {'Range': 'bytes={}-{}'.format(start, end), 'User-Agent': 'ssup'}
    headers = sign_headers(headers, endpoint, access_key, secret_key)

    # Raw message to send via socket
    s3_message_parts = ['GET {} HTTP/1.1',
                        'Host: {}',
                        'Connection: keep-alive',
                        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
                        'Accept: */*',
                        'User-Agent: ssup',
                        'X-Amz-Content-Sha256: UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD',
                        'Range: bytes={}-{}',
                        'X-Amz-Date: {}',
                        'Authorization: {}',
                        '\r\n']
    message_params = '/' + bucket + '/' + key, headers['Host'], start, end, headers['X-Amz-Date'], headers['Authorization']

    s3_download_message = '\r\n'.join(s3_message_parts).format(message_params)

    s = ssl.wrap_socket(socket.socket())
    s.connect(('s3.amazonaws.com', 443))
    s.sendall(s3_download_message)

    #Implement proper retrieval loop  
    return s.recv(), s.recv()

if __name__=='__main__':

    # Adjust to get arguments from command prompt
    from sys import argv as args

    # Credentials
    access_key = 'access'
    secret_key = 'secret'

    # Bucket, key and location info
    bucket = 'my_bucket'
    key = 'my_key'

    # Chunk of key to download
    start = 20
    end = 100

    header, chunk = download_s3_chunk(bucket, key, start, end, access_key, secret_key)
```

The logic is pretty portable, as long as sha256 and hmac implementations exist. Hope this comes handy.

Answer (score 0):

If you're JUST trying to download the contents of the file for use within python, here's the short version of my code.

```
import boto3

aws = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='maintenance')
s3 = aws.client('s3, region_name='us-west-2')

data = s3.get_object(
    Bucket='my_bucket_name',
    Key='/path/of/s3/key'
)['Body'].read()
```

Now you have the entire file and you can do with it as you will with other code.

Edit:  It sounds like you don't have the credentials or anything set up, yet.  boto3 (and most amazon CLI products) want a credentials file in the below format:

Name:  `~/.aws/credentials`

```
[default]
aws_secret_access_key = 9087OKLJHAFWSKLDJGHNAKLJHWR34K (random keys typed by me)
aws_access_key_id = MORERANDOMKEYSTOFILLTHESPACE
```

Create that file and I think you'll be set.

Comment: boto3 is a great library, and has the 'Range=' which I need here to download part of the file. However, I wish to know how to do it in "vanilla" python. Appreciate the help

Comment: @Jay Saying that you want to do it in "vanilla" python is like saying you wish to do it in binary machine code. It is more complicated, prone to errors, likely to break in future and difficult to implement. You are using Python because it is easier than writing in raw machine code. For the same reason, you should use the boto3 library that is provided by AWS and supported by AWS.

Comment: So, you don't have a specific requirement for it, you simply want to write the interaction with the REST api yourself.  You could have just said that.

Comment: So are the vanilla examples. AWS